# Change reference depends on another column

Tags: database, postgresql

i have table with two main columns (object_ID and object_type) and some columns, that describes this object (that columns are the same to all objects, cause of this i need this table):

1) object_type contains type of another column

2) object_ID - contains ID of object, that references on table, that describes this object.
But its one problem, it can reference to multiple tables depends on object_type.

F.e. if object_type = book, then object_ID will references table books, etc. (it can be many objects)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` definitions for all the tables involved, please?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do? Do you want to query a table (e.g. `books`) with a certain `object_id` associated with `object_type = book`? Can you post a pseudo-query?